# Blank page is shown when pop the fragment & replace to the same fragment again

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have 3 fragments, Frag_A, Frag_B & Frag_C.

My navigation logic is: Frag_A ==> Frag_B ==> Frag_C .  That's Frag_A is added into layout firstly, so, at the first time, Frag_A is shown on screen, then, if user press the Next Button, Frag_A is replaced by Frag_B, now Frag_B is shown on screen, if user press the Next button, Frag_B is replaced by Frag_C, so that Frag_C is shown on screen.

**Everything works fine with my code at this point.**

Method to change to next fragment:

```
//here, argument 'fragment' is either Frag_B or Frag_C
public void showFragment(Fragment fragment){
   FragmentManager fragMgr = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMgr.beginTransaction();

  fragTrans.replace(R.id.frag_placeholder, fragment, fragmentName);
  fragTrans.addToBackStack(null);

  int transId = fragTrans.commit();
  fragMgr.executePendingTransactions();

}
```

Layout file of activity (Frag_A is added to the frag_placeholder when Activity starts):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >

     <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/frag_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      />
</merge>
```

But, after Frag_C is shown, if I **pop** Frag_C by press the physical back button and invoke the `showFragment(Frag_C)` method to show the Frag_C again right after my code detected the physical button is pressed, **I get a blank page** shown on screen. Why & how to fix it?

**================Explain=====================**

I said above "*show the Frag_C again right after my code detected the physical button is pressed*", here is what I mean:

In Activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed();
  //I detect the Physical Back button is pressed & invoke the method to show the popped Frag_C again.
}
```

Comment: *right after my code detected the physical button is pressed,* - what does this mean exactly?

Comment: Please check my explanation in OP

Comment: A wild guess... do you use the `showFragment()` method with the same instance of the fragment? Also that seems a bit strange, the user removes the fragment only for you to show it again.

Comment: @ Luksprog, my code is a prove of concept of one of our product, I won't describe the reason why I do it, but this is the logic I need. But for your 1st question, yes, I am using the same instance of Frag_C

Comment: Well instead of what you currently do(and I really don't understand that behavior) either use a new instance of that fragment or in the `onBackPressed()` simply cancel the event if you're at the target fragment(not sure it will work).

Comment: @ Luksprog, please put your comment in an answer, since after I used a new instance of the fragment(Frag_C), the blank page isn't shown anymore, though I got another error "Frag_C is not attached to Activity", I am wondering why also, but your suggestion did solve my current problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @ Luksprog 's comment, I found that if I create a **new instance** of `Frag_C` instead of always use the same instance, the blank page problem get fixed.

Comment: But creating new instance take more memory.

Comment: I stumbled upon the same problem, apparently it is not fixed until now october 2017, and I want to avoid creating new fragments each time. Gonna investigate more into details, please share if you have any info